# Mongo pool connection AWS issue

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Since migrating to AWS we started to experience strange issues having broken pipe randomly

It seems that by default spring data mongodb creates two connections in the pool but most of the time uses only one and performs health-check only for that one.
AWS's load balancer closes the second connection after 10 minutes of inactivity without notifying the server. Once in a while server tries to use the second connection but it's closed so the exception is thrown.
As a temporary workaround I added

```
.applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder -> {
                builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(9, MINUTES);
            })
```

so we "refresh" the second connections ourselves but I would like to have a better solution so here are two qestions:

- is there a way to enforce spring to use other connections more often?
- is there a way to add heartbeat to all connections in the pool